# C++ code meaning and conversion in Java

Tags: java, c++

I have in C++

```
char *s, mask;
// Some code

If(*s == 0){ //Some more code}

If(*s & mask){ //Some code}
```

In Java can I write this like

```
byte s,mask;
//Some code 
If(s == (byte)0x0){ //Some more code}   
If((s & mask) != (byte)0x0){ //Some Code}
```

Is the java code correct?

Comment: Are you writing character set conversion ? `<whistle/>`

Comment: Yes we are initializing the s variable both in C++ and Java.

Comment: [Pointers and Pointer arithmetic](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eskimo.com%2F~scs%2Fcclass%2Fnotes%2Fsx10b.html&ei=bQb_TZ_rF8qDOuu_-N4I&usg=AFQjCNEnf6tbYW7gRWMKAmEKfgaRN79j1w&sig2=7Jue_8LvfEbajpu_vzvz4A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the C++ code really say `if (*s == 0)`, or does it really say `if (s == 0)`? In the first, you're checking if what `s` points to is 0, while in the second, you're checking if `s` is a null pointer. Those are two very different things.

Java doesn't have pointers, so this code cannot be translated to Java directly.

Comment: in *s == 0 . *s points to the object or what? So is it checking the object is empty or wat?

Comment: `*s` is the thing that `s` points to - it is checking if the thing that `s` points to is 0. There's no object involved, `s` is a pointer to `char`. It's checking if the `char` that `s` points to is 0. In C, strings are usually zero-terminated, so this looks like checking if a string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the default value of an uninitialized pointers in undefined. You have to initialize it explicitly. In Java, the default value of a variable of type `byte` is `0`, unless it is a local variable, in which case you have to initialize it explicitly too.

Comment: But only for member variables; local variables are not initialized to a default value, you must initialize to some value explicitly, and if you don't you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ this code is undefined behavior:

```
If(*s == 0)  // 's' is not initialized
```

I think in Java, eclipse type of editor might complain for uninitialized `s`. It's a good practice to initialize a variable in any of the language before reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely translation you'd want to do (this looks like some kind of lowlevel parsing; for scanning of binary byte arrays, 'unsigned char' would have been expected):

```
byte[] s; // with some kind of value
for (int i=0; i<s.Length; i++)
{
     if (s[i] == 0x0){ //Some more code}   
     if ((s[i] & mask) != 0x0){ //Some Code}
}
```

(*untouched by compilees, and my java is swamped by years of C++ and C# :)*)

Answer (score 0):

this should be equivalent to your C++ code:

```
    byte s[], mask;

    if (s[0] == 0) { /*Some more code*/ }

    if ((s[0] & mask) != 0) {/*Some code*/}
```

@sehe pointed out `s` is likely to get **incremented** in the C++ code -- in which case `s[0]` should change to `s[pos]` in the Java example:

```
    byte s[], mask;
    // initialize s[] to store enough bytes
    int pos;
    if (s[pos = 0] == 0) { pos++; /* Some code */ }

    if ((s[pos] & mask) != 0) {/*Some code*/}
```

Comment: this defies the fact that the code not shown will almost certainly increment s

Comment: Interesting guess. Even so, this is a decent C++ to Java mapping assuming `char* s` is an array of bytes. I will update the answer to reflect the potential increment of `s`

Comment: mmm... assignment inside the indexer, single post-increment at _start_ of 'some code'; I think my version of it looks a lot more 'canonical' (even if pos++ is at the right spot, you'd write `continue` in my for loop)

Comment: @sehe, sure, whatever. we don't even knwo what the OP wants

Comment: hehe -- funny how SO works like that :). I usually leave these questions alone. My goal is _not to add_ confusion.